# How to use IN clause in CDbCriteria with CActiveDataProvider in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, controller

Here is my working code, without IN clause conditions -

```
   $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('UserInfo',
        array('id'=>'user-detail',
          'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'id DESC', 
                  'attributes'=>array('id', 'fname', 'lname', 'city')
            ),
         'criteria' => array(
                'condition' => 'Staus=:Staus',
                'params' => array(':Staus' => 1),
           ),
        'pagination'=>array
            (
                'pageSize'=>10)
            )
        );
```

Now i also want to use IN clause in the condition, how can use?
I'm trying like this, but getting error - Array to string conversion

```
'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'Staus=:Staus, id=:id',
            'params' => array(':Staus' => 1, ':id' => array(1,4,10,15,20)),
       ),
```

Please help me to resolve my issue, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Closed]**
I'm getting the answer from Yii Forum -

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addColumnCondition(array('Staus'=>1));
$criteria->addInCondition('id', array(1,4,10,15,20));

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('UserInfo', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ...
));
```

It's working perfect for me :)..

Courtesy - [Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57387-how-to-use-in-clause-in-cdbcriteria-with-cactivedataprovider-in-yii/page__p__260093#entry260093)

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->compare('Staus',1);
    $criteria->addInCondition('id',array(1,4,10,15,20));

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('UserInfo',
    array('id'=>'user-detail',
      'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'id DESC', 
              'attributes'=>array('id', 'fname', 'lname', 'city')
        ),
     'criteria' => $criteria,
    'pagination'=>array
        (
            'pageSize'=>10)
        )
    );
```

Comment: thanks for this :).. but why are use `$criteria->compare('Staus',1)` ?

Comment: It is same as where condition, just more neat.